# Why does >= work but => not?

Tags: c#, operators

When checking if a integer is the same or above a current number.. so I type

```
if (5 => 6) { //Bla }
```

but it shows this as a error. Why?  Isn't it exactly the same as

```
if (5 >= 6) { //Bla }
```

Comment: It is just not the correct syntax.

Comment: In nearly every programming language it is >= and <= and is considered the correct format by mathematicians.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The reason why it does not work is because `=>` is not equivalent to `>=`.

`=>` is used in a [lambda expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx). Like :

```
(int x, string s) => s.Length > x
```

I do agree it is annoying. Before lambda expressions I used to get it wrong sometimes. Now I always know that one (`=>`) is a *lambda expression* and and other (`>=`) is the *greater than equal to* sign

Comment: I keep doing it wrong since I think like I posted in the comment of BoltClock

Comment: C# lambda syntax came decades after settling on >= as the "Greater Than Or Equal To" operator in languages of the curly brace family.

Answer (score 11):

Because the operator is `>=` not `=>`.

The writers of the language could have chosen either syntax, but had to choose one. Having two operators meaning the same thing would be confusing at best.

However, the operator is read "greater than or equal to" so it does make sense that the `>` symbol is first.

Also `=>` is now used for Lambda expressions.

Answer (score 6):

Because `=>` is meant for lambda expressions:

```
Action<object> print = o => Console.WriteLine(o);
print(123);
```

Besides, you don't say "equal to or greater than", which is what `=>` would have been pronounced as otherwise.

Comment: Unrelated, but Erlang picked `=<` and `>=`, so "you don't say 'equal to or less than'" fails in at least one oddball language. :)

Comment: @sarnold: Well you got me there :P

Comment: Imo, you first check wether a number is the same as the number to you want to compare it against and then check wether it is higher or lower. So => and =<.  Because it is easy'r to check wether a number is the same using the very basics of understanding.  When you need to check wether a number is higher, or lower, you'll have to start with the base number and count up or down. Therefor, I was wondering why =< and => doesn't work.  Your answer about => being for lambda will make me accept this as a answer as you were the first to say it !

Comment: @Levisaxos: Nah, giddy came first :)

Comment: Accepting giddy's as answer then. Upvoted for your honesty :)

Answer (score 6):

The confusion here is that you're assuming >= is two operators smooshed together.  In fact, it's only one operator with two characters, much the same as tons of other operators (+=, *=, -=, etc).

Answer (score 4):

Why should it be? =! is not the same as != either. This is a part of the languages syntax.

In this specific case, => is also used for lambda expressions so it has another purpose.

Answer (score 2):

Because it is called greater or equal to. Not equal or greater than. Simple uh?

Answer (score 1):

In C# the greater than or less than sign must come BEFORE the equal sign.  It is just part of the syntax of the language.

Answer (score 1):

Because `=>` stands for Lambda expressions in c#.

`>=` stands for greater than or equal to, as you already know.

The syntax is such that you have to use `>=` while comparing two entities. Also just additionally you can notice that even a space between them will give errors - `> =`

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not this same. Correct operator in c# is >= for comparission and => for lambda expression.

Answer (score 0):

@Barry's answer is probably the most insightful of the lot here. A single operator does not mean a single character; the fact that `>` and `=` combine to form `>=` does not mean that it's doing both `>` and `=`; it's doing a single operation. The fact that the defined operator for that operation includes the characters for two other similar operations is irrelevent.

I suppose if you *really* wanted to you could override it so that both `>=` and `=>` worked the same way -- C# does allow operator overrides. But it would be a bad idea because as others have already said, `=>` is actually in use for other purposes.