# "Greater than" or "equal" vs "equal" or "greater than" in python

Tags: python, boolean-logic

why is it that we use "greater than" or "equal", rather than "equal" or "greater than"?

```
foo = 1

if foo >= 1:
  print("Greater than 1")
>>> Greater than 1
```

while the following would raise a `SyntaxError`:

```
foo = 1

if a => 1:
  print("Greater than 1")
```

why does it make a difference in what order you use the comparison operators?

Comment: `>=` is one single comparison operator. It's not two operators in a specific order.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does >= work but => not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5648771/why-does-work-but-not)

Comment: @benjamin That's about C#, not Python, though it might be still a bit useful

Comment: I could have sworn this would be a duplicate, but I couldn't find one [even with a SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1813707).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`>=` is one operator, not two. Same with `<=`. As for why the order is the way it is in modern programming languages, the answer is just 'convention'.

The decision to make it `>=`/`<=` rather than `=>`/`=<` is by convention, and is common among nearly all existing programming languages that use comparison operators at all. The oldest programming languages that used comparison operators, to my knowledge, are FORTRAN and COBOL, both of which follow the `>=`/`<=` convention.

I dunno if there was more design rationale behind it at the beginning, besides that in mathematics we say "greater than or equal to", rather than "equal to or greater than", and thus `>=` more accurately reflects that.

As for why `=>` and `=<` are not valid, it's mostly to avoid redundancy and/or confusion. Python has a principle that "there should be one, and preferably only one, obvious way to do things", but this is also the case in every other language I know of. Notably, `=>` has an *entirely different meaning* in some other programming languages, most notably Javascript, where it denotes a lambda expression.

Comment: Interesting to note that Unicode has _several_ variants of greater-than or equal in the same character, but no programing language that actually got some use uses any of them - '⩾', '≥', '≧', '⪖', (and the correspondent "less-than or equal")

Comment: @jsbueno Probably because it's impossible to type them on a US English keyboard. Speaking of, are there any programming languages that actually accept non-ASCII special characters? (Esoteric languages excluded.) IIRC, Powershell accepts curly quotes, but mostly to accommodate copy-pasting.

Comment: Python lets you use non-ASCII characters in names as long as they are alphanumeric.

Comment: @kindall Good point. I meant to say non-ASCII *special* characters. Edited comment.

Comment: BTW, there are some (older) languages in which you can write `>=` or `=>` interchangeably. It works in Applesoft BASIC, for example (just tried it in an emulator). I should also mention that Python used to support the BASIC-like `<>` for "not equal to," but they removed that in 3.0.

Comment: I brought out the comment exactly because every other week one approaches Python's development forums trying to push these kind of characters - and yes, due to inputting then being non trivial (not only on US English, but on most keyboard layout), the proposals are early dismissed. (Though, there would be other problems as well, and I am in general against it).

Comment: That said, the one language that had actually seem some traction using different symbols than the ones found in the ASCII table is "APL" - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/APL_(programming_language)

Answer (score -1):

The simple answer: It is just how the syntax works.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question, it just pushes the "why" one step back. Why is that how the syntax works? As well, it doesn't address OP's second question at all, *"why does it make a difference in what order you use the comparison operators?"*

Comment: There are surely a great amount of reasons why python went this way but it's just syntax.

There is really no point explaing why, it's just how it is - it is not going to change.

There isn't really why or not, if I wanted I could make my language where those two are different order.

Comment: You may believe there is no point explaining why, but in that case you believe there is no point answering the question.

Comment: Greek cloak guy posted a 4 paragraph answer - amazing. But read it and you come into conclusion - It is just how it was designed because the authors chose this syntax over another, if they wanted they could do different.

Comment: If you believe it is a pointless question then you should downvote the question, not answer it. I don't believe it is a pointless question, and the fact that it has received an upvoted answer suggests the community doesn't believe it is a pointless question either.

Comment: @Dawid OK, but Green gives *probable reasons* for that choice. You don't have to read the designers' minds to know that `>=` is the convention, Python avoids redundancy, and that `=>` could be confusing for people who know JS.

Comment: @wjandrea You have your point, I have my point - In my opinion the simplest answer was the best, but I am no one to say that everyone should agree.